# In video.js, how to solve the buffering problem by using playlist.m3u8 file format

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I can't find my solution. I am going to play the playlist.m3u8 file with video tag of html5 in my website.

Below is my javascript code.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <video id="my-video" class="video-js" autoplay preload="auto" muted="false">
        </video>
    </body>

<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js"></script>
<script>
    var myPlayer = videojs('my-video'); 
    myPlayer.src('https://5bf6159570fba.streamlock.net/Bwin/Horses_0/playlist.m3u8');
    myPlayer.play();
</script>
```

And at regular intervals i use the myPlayer.reset() function.

Contents of playlist.m3u8 file is below.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2566576,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=960x540
chunklist_w1328950476.m3u8
```

Contents of chunklist_w1328950476.m3u8 file is below.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:2.0,
media_w1328950476_1.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media_w1328950476_2.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media_w1328950476_3.ts
```

If i run above code, the following error codes are dislayed at console.

```
video.js:142 VIDEOJS: ERROR: DOMException: Failed to set the 'duration' property on 'MediaSource': 
The 'updating' attribute is true on one or more of this MediaSource's SourceBuffers.
at HtmlMediaSource.addSeekableRange_ (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:49141:44)
at addSeekableRange (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:55039:36)
at PlaylistLoader.<anonymous> (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:55054:15)
at PlaylistLoader.data.dispatcher (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:1818:33)
at trigger (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:1954:27)
at PlaylistLoader.EventTarget.trigger (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:2432:5)
at PlaylistLoader.haveMetadata (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:39151:14)
at https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:39089:17
at Object.callback (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:40086:9)
at cbOnce (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js:7220:17)
```

And Status of media_w1328950476_6.ts file is **(cancelled)**.

I would appreciate it if you could find a solution to this problem as soon as possible.

Thanks for your time and attention

Comment: I'm confused about you saying you use 'reset()' at regular intervals.  I don't see any of your javascript code that does that. (???)

Comment: sorry, above code is called at regular interval. e.x every 120s. so, after executing above code, i call reset() function.

Comment: You can ignore this function.

Comment: Did you make any progress? We're experiencing buffering in m3u8 playlists as well